# How to put array having spaced values in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to split a series of numbers into digits. I have splitted the digits using strsplit. The dataset that I have after splitting is like -

```
strings <- c("001", "002", "003", "004")
dataset <- strsplit(strings, split="")
dataset

[[1]]
[1] "0" "0" "1"

[[2]]
[1] "0" "0" "2"

[[3]]
[1] "0" "0" "3"

[[4]]
[1] "0" "0" "4"
```

Now , I want to put this into a data frame so that each number comes in a separate column for all values in the array.
Like this -

```
## V1 V2 V3
##  0  0  1
##  0  0  2
##  .
##  .
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ldply` from the `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)

ldply(strsplit(as.character(dataset),split=""))

##    V1 V2 V3
## 1   0  0  1
## 2   0  0  2
## 3   0  0  3
## 4   0  0  4
## 5   0  0  5
## 6   0  0  6
## 7   0  0  7
## 8   0  0  8
## 9   0  0  9
## 10  0  1  0
## 11  0  1  1
## 12  0  1  2
## 13  0  1  3
```

Comment: Thanks!    Installing package into ‘/home/harsh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘plyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)     Is it possible without plyr?

Comment: The `plyr` package is available on [CPAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html).  However, I am using version 3.2.3 of R.

Comment: Yes, you can do something similar to what is in @petermeissner's answer: `as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(dataset),split="")))`

Comment: if plyr is availible, thats the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

that should do the trick ...

```
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, dataset))
```

... if all strings are of the same length.

If not, things get a little bit more tricky but this should do:

```
do.call(
  plyr::rbind.fill, 
  lapply(
    dataset, 
    function(x){as.data.frame(t(cbind(x)))}
  )
)
```

or

```
library(plyr
do.call(
  rbind.fill, 
  lapply(
    dataset, 
    function(x){as.data.frame(t(cbind(x)))}
  )
)
```

In case plyr is not an option one can make one's own version of rbind-fill ...

```
#' function for binding data.frames even if names do not match
#' @param df1 first data.frame to rbind
#' @param df2 second data.frame to rbind
#' @keywords internal

rbind_fill <- function(df1=data.frame(), df2=data.frame()){
    names_df <- c(names(df1), names(df2))
    if( dim(df1)[1] > 0 ){
        df1[, names_df[!(names_df %in% names(df1))]] <- rep(NA, dim(df1)[1])
    }else{
        df1 <- data.frame()
    }
    if( dim(df2)[1] > 0 ){
        df2[, names_df[!(names_df %in% names(df2))]] <- rep(NA, dim(df2)[1])
    }else{
        df2 <- data.frame()
    }
    rbind(df1, df2)
}

do.call(
  rbind_fill, 
  lapply(
    dataset, 
    function(x){as.data.frame(t(cbind(x)))}
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks!   Installing package into ‘/home/harsh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) Warning message: package ‘plyr’ is not available (for R version 3.0.2)                Is it possible without plyr?

Comment: `do.call(rbind, dataset)` works out of the box; try updating your R and try installing plyr again; I think the data.table package has an rbind-fill function as well

Comment: @petermeissner I believe your first `do.call` command outputs a matrix, not a data frame (that is how it worked for me).  You will have to convert the matrix to a data frame.